# How to reset bash to factory settings mac

Tags: bash, mac, terminal

I have tried every solution the internet has to offer. I have no experience with bash i'm a dummy. whenever i open terminal, this shows:

```
$ PS1="\W \$"; clear;
```

I want to remove all PS1 exports. I deleted the bash profile, but nothing happened. If I nano .bash_profile, its empty. However, I still get this. How do I completely reset all bash modifications to factory settings?

Comment: [Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) lists a number of other places to check.

Comment: I have a bash swap file what does that do could it be of use here?

Comment: That has [nothing to do](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/1972793?start=0) with your bash prompt.

Comment: I dont have a bash login or .profile file?

Comment: I repeat, [Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html) lists a number of other places to check.

Comment: I checked them all, i cant edit the bashrc that has this ps1 command

Comment: # System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.
if [ -z "$PS1" ]; then
   return
fi

PS1='\h:\W \u\$ '
# Make bash check its window size after a process completes
shopt -s checkwinsize

[ -r "/etc/bashrc_$TERM_PROGRAM" ] && . "/etc/bashrc_$TERM_PROGRAM"

Comment: I just want to remove all PS1 commands from the bash startup files, but I've looked everywhere and cant where i have permission

Comment: You can override `PS1` in one of your personal bash startup files.

Comment: how do I set a custom bash startup file? As i said my ~/.bash_profile is empty but how do I point shell to always use that?

Comment: {sigh} Read the link I gave you twice already. "When Bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as a non-interactive shell with the --login option, it first reads and executes commands from the file /etc/profile, if that file exists. After reading that file, it looks for ~/.bash_profile, ~/.bash_login, and ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists and is readable. "

Comment: Yeah I did read it, but going through these files in that order, I do not see the PS1="\W \$"; clear; command that I wanna get rid of anywhere

Comment: Add `env -u PS1` or ` unset PS1` to `~/.bash_profile`. Better still change `PS1` to what you want it to be. I have `PS1='$ '
export PS1` (two lines).

Comment: [how to view, edit, unset and delete an environment variable in linux](http://www.lostsaloon.com/technology/how-to-view-edit-and-delete-an-environment-variable-in-linux/)

Comment: None of those solve the problem, although they do change the shell which shows at least the file is being read. could there be any other files that havent been listed in that article where the ps1 files could lie?

Comment: I've no idea...

Comment: when i try and list environment variables using ~ $echo $PS1 it only returns \W $ even though PS1="\W \$"; clear;

Comment: really strange ...

Comment: oh guess what, I had to reset terminal plist file as well